# Horror story where people are sent to alternate dimensions for a reality TV show

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

The movie was about a sister that goes missing. A group of 5 teenagers go looking for her in the woods. They end up in another dimension. Then the sister (the one looking for missing one) finds out that there’s multiple dimensions all with different monsters, and it’s actually broadcast on reality TV.

There was a creepy shop owner that wants them to get a necklace from his wife that disappeared into the woods. Come to find out, he sends people into these dimensions for the reality TV.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When did you watch this movie, and when do you think it might've been made?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [The Axiom](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6051096/) from 2018.

> At the risk of her group's safety, a young woman travels into a National Forest where her sister has become trapped in a multi-dimensional world of monsters.

It's all there, including the old guy asking them to retrieve his wife's necklace. Here's the trailer: